# Website not loading on my laptop but just fine on other devices

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, web, hosting, web-hosting

So I launched my very own WordPress website today for the first time and while building it I took a break. Before taking the break I decided that I should transfer my DNS to Cloudflare as they give you free DDOS protection. For some reason, due to this my server immediately crashed. Luckily I had a backup and restarted the website with that server. However, the problem is from my laptop I'm no longer able to access the website, every time it just says "This site can’t be reached" but when I try to open the website from my phone or my sister's laptop everything works fine. I tried using a VPN on my laptop and initially, that worked but when I go to the WordPress login page it gives me the same "This site can’t be reached". Although when I'm on my phone or my sister's laptop, I'm able to login to WordPress just fine. To see if it makes a different I restarted my laptop and that worked and fixed everything, until 10 minutes later when I had the same issue happen. I've tried chrome, firefox, edge, all have the same issue. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What response do you get when you ping your website URL from your computer ?

If it is able to ping then you do not have a connection issue between your computer and the web server. Perhaps you have some application such as a firewall on your computer is blocking one or more ports that web browsers use. Check if you have something blocking port 80 (HTTP), port 443 (HTTPS) or port 8080 (HTTP Alternate).